# Add JScrollPane to JPanel

Tags: java, eclipse, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I try to make a scrollbar for a JPanel but when I RUN, the scrollbar not even show up.

**EDITED: This is the latest code, I updated the contentPane layout.**

This is main Panel:

```
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 400));
setContentPane(contentPane);
```

This is JPanel inside the main Panel:

```
bigPanel = new JPanel();
bigPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1137, 520));

bigPanel.setBackground(new Color(224, 255, 255));

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(bigPanel);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));

scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);   
contentPane.add(scrollPane,"1, 2, 6, 1, center, default");   
bigPanel.setLayout(new FormLayout(new ColumnSpec[] {...}
bigPanel.add(BUTTON1);
bigPanel.add(BUTTON2);.....
```

Above code was written under:

```
public UI2(){...}
```

This is the launch application code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                UI2 frame = new UI2();                      
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(UI2.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(1376,788);                
                frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

bigPanel has many buttons. So I need a vertical and horizontal scrollbar within bigPanel.

This is the screenshot after I RUN but no scrollbar shown:
[image: bigPanel is with green background]

**EDITED: This is the latest screenshot, the bigPanel shows empty after I wrote the code as above.**
[image]

Comment: Change `contentPane.add(BigPanel,"1, 2, 6, 1, center, default");` to `contentPane.add(scrollPane,"1, 2, 6, 1, center, default");`? You should be adding the JScrollPane to the contentPane, if I am not wrong.

Comment: @Gosu I tried it then bigPanel shows empty(the buttons all gone)

Comment: Is that your actual code? `BigPanel = new JPanel();` doesn't seem correct.. and `BigPanel.setBounds(162, 157, 1137, 520);` seems wrong too.. Provide a runnable example please, thanks! :)

Comment: @Gosu Yes I use that code, the components are shown.. Can I know why you said it seems wrong?

Comment: because of the `BigPanel` and `bigPanel` which you just edited.

Comment: try to set the preferred size of bigPanel.

Comment: @Garry I tried `bigPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1137, 520));` but all components inside bigPanel gone

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: I believe the problem is with `contentPane.setLayout(null);`, which means that the `JScrollPane` has not definable size and is not been shown because of it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I updated the contentPane layout, is this the right as what you said? I use GroupLayout for contentPane. The bigPanel not showing up

Comment: I wouldn't use GroupLayout, personally, I might use GridBagLayt, but that would depend on what you want to achieve. Remeber, you can use multiple containers with different layouts to combine together to achieve the ultimate result ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with `contentPane.setLayout(null);`, which means that the `JScrollPane` has not definable size and is not been shown because of it.

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Also `contentPane.add(BigPanel,"1, 2, 6, 1, center, default");` should be `contentPane.add(scrollPane,"1, 2, 6, 1, center, default");`.  Once you correct for the layout issue, the scroll pane should become visible

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more ideas

Comment: Thank you so much Sir! I owe you one. I use GridBagLayout for contentPane and the scrollPane shown. Plus, it also helps me to arrange the components more easier

Answer (score 0):

To force a JScrollPane to always display scroll bars, set the visibility policy:

```
ScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(panel);
sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `bigPanel.setBounds(162, 157, 1137, 520);`
call `bigPanel.setPreferredSize(1137, 520);` then JScrollPane can use the content size

UPDATE
`bigPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1137, 520));`

Comment: I tried but it shows error `The method setPreferredSize(Dimension) in the type JComponent is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)` @StanislavL

Comment: I tried bigPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1137, 520)); but all components inside bigPanel gone

Comment: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: The problem is not setPreferredSize but guess null layout. Either use a LayoutManager (recommended way) or place all children components properly in the bigPanel